# Sum two integers in Java

Tags: java, variables, java.util.scanner

Im trying to sum two numbers from user input. But its not working

This is what I have done

```
import java.util.*;

public class EX2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    int y;

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    x.nextInt();

    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    y.nextInt();

    int sum = x + y;

    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

the error code is

```
Error:(12, 17) java: variable x is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
Error:(13, 10) java: int cannot be dereferenced
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can't declare `x` as both `int` and `Scanner`... Same for `y`...

Comment: Give your variables different names.  Calling *everything* `x` and `y` will confuse both you and the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You reused the `x` and `y` variable names (hence the `variable x is already defined in method main` error), and forgot to assign the `int`s read from the `Scanner` to the `x` and `y` variables.

Besides, there's no need to create two `Scanner` objects.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x;
    int y;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = sc.nextInt();
    y = sc.nextInt();

    int sum = x + y;

    System.out.println(x +" "+ y);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that the scanner and an integer are sharing the same name?

```
int x;
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
```

That is invalid in Java. Think about using a more descriptive name for the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Output {
   public static void main(String[] args)
{

/*
Step 1. Declare Variables 
*/

int varX;
int varY;
int sum;

/*
Step 2. Create a Scanner to take in user input
*/

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

/*
Step 3. varX and varY will take in the next two integers the user enters
*/

varX = scan.nextInt();
varY = scan.nextInt();

sum = varX + varY;

/*
Step 4. Print out the two chosen integers and display the sum
*/

System.out.println(varX + " + " + varY + " equals " + sum);
System.out.println(sum);
}

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.